# Bibtex entry to cite an article with unknown author?

Tags: bibtex

Which bibtex entry type should I use to cite an article in a professional/popular (i.e. non peer reviewed) magazine. The article does not state an author, and bibtex article entry requires an author.

I found that the citation should be something like this

‘Tax-free savings push’, Sunday Mail (4 April 1999), p. 3.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@misc{tfsp,
key={Tax-free},
title={Tax-free savings push},
howpublished={Sunday Mail},
year={4 April 1999},
pages={3},
}
```

In the `@misc` type all fields are optional. Use a suitable `key` field.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think Bibtex **requires** that the author field is filled out. In my case (Bibliography built with JabRef and Biblatex package), I use an article entry with an empty author field when there is no indication of the author in the magazine (often the case with popular magazines).
Tha advantage over using a misc entry, in my opinion, is to keep the same presentation for journal and article title as with the other article entry with an author.